error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL (EDIT:::: A silly mistake)
So i was initializing the backend for my project using ,
Hono, Prisma , postgres and cloudfare workers as serverless backend.
I am getting this error,
Ps : this is my index ts file
import { Hono } from 'hono'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client/edge'
import { withAccelerate } from '@prisma/extension-accelerate'
import { decode, sign, verify } from 'hono/jwt'


const app = new Hono<{
     Bindings: {
         DATABASE_URL: string
     }
    }>()

app.get('/', (c) => {

  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})

app.post('/api/v1/signup',async (c)=>{
 const prisma= new PrismaClient({
    datasourceUrl: c.env.DATABASE_URL,

 }).$extends(withAccelerate());

 const body = await c.req.json();

 const user= await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: body.email,
      password: body.password,
    }, 
 })
 const token = await sign({id: user.id}, "secret")
 return c.json({
  jwt: token
 })
  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})

app.post('/api/v1/signin',(c)=>{
  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})
app.post('/api/v1/blog',(c)=>{
  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})
app.put('/api/v1/blog',(c)=>{
  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})
app.get('/api/v1/blog/:id',(c)=>{
  return c.text('Hello Hono!')
})
export default app


This is my .env file
DATABASE_URL="postgres://avnadmin:AVNS_noTY3p1vOQAtf3xI5Ip@pg-4e7409b-works-3ccb.j.aivencloud.com:15487/defaultdb?sslmode=require"

this is my wrangler.toml file
name = "backend"
main = "src/index.ts"
compatibility_date = "2024-12-05"

# compatibility_flags = [ "nodejs_compat" ]

# [vars] 

> ***(this is the mistake , i forgot to remove the #)***

DATABASE_URL="prisma://accelerate.prisma-data.net/?api_key=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcGlfa2V5IjoiOTMyMzExMjUtMDQ4My00YWE5LWI1ZjAtOTIxZmI2OWVhYmI0IiwidGVuYW50X2lkIjoiZjVjMTliZDllYjBlNjEyZjU4M2E0NjAwNzUwNDQ0MWIwMGJiYzRlODljZjllNTQ3NTVkNGU5MWMwMzEzMmM0MSIsImludGVybmFsX3NlY3JldCI6IjM4ZDc1NDFlLWQ2YTMtNDBlOS05YzA3LTY5MTk2ZTJkMzExYSJ9.C0jIpM8NfJB0PIh_UC0xLvpStJJTRnuOLmqUbh066CI"

this is my schema.prisma file
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id       String  @id @default(uuid())
  email    String  @unique
  name     String?
  password String
  posts    Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        String  @id @default(uuid())
  title     String
  content   String
  published Boolean @default(false)
  authorId  String
  author    User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
}

ps: ive ran npx prisma generate as well
sent this request using postman
but it is not working
